# How to correctly save data in a BelongsToMany Associations?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.7

My app manages repair orders for an electronic products workshop.
when I try to save several identical items (with the same id), cake keeps only the last entry, ignoring previous ones. (In my example, the last product)

I was trying to configure the "saveStrategy" in the model, trying with "append", but I had no results. When I enter different products (with different ids), it saves it with no problems.

### Tables:

**Tickets**

```
| id | client_id | reference |
```

**Products**

```
| id | code | description |
```

**Products_Tickets**

```
| id | ticket_id | product_id | qty | serial_number | notes |
```

---

```
debug($this->request->getData());

[
    'client_id' => '1',
    'reference' => 'Client reference',
    'products' => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'id' => '1',
            '_joinData' => [
                'qty' => '1',
                'serial_number' => '123',
                'notes' => 'Not working'
            ]
        ],
        (int) 1 => [
            'id' => '1',
            '_joinData' => [
                'qty' => '1',
                'serial_number' => '345',
                'notes' => 'Not Working too'
            ]
        ],
        (int) 2 => [
            'id' => '1',
            '_joinData' => [
                'qty' => '1',
                'serial_number' => '567',
                'notes' => 'Note number 3'
            ]
        ],
        (int) 3 => [
            'id' => '1',
            '_joinData' => [
                'qty' => '1',
                'serial_number' => '978',
                'notes' => 'Another note'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

It supposed to save is all the data, not only the last value.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the relation between Products and Tickets that you set? I think it should be `Products` `belongsToMany` `Products`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your business case correctly, you are creating a ticket for a client and in the same transaction you are adding 4 products to the ticket.  So you are adding a ticket with 4 associated product_tickets (the items on the ticket).

In the model ProductsTable.php

```
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('products');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->hasMany('ProductTickets', [
            'foreignKey' => 'product_id'
        ]);
    }
```

In the model TicketsTable.php

```
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('tickets');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->hasMany('ProductTickets', [
            'foreignKey' => 'ticket_id'
        ]);
    }
```

In the model ProductTicketsTable.php

```
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('product_tickets');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Tickets', [
            'foreignKey' => 'ticket_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Products', [
            'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }
```

Then you can use the Tickets controller only and save with associated ProductTickets (the ticket line items).

So, in `src\Template\Tickets\add.php`, you can set up the form like this:

```
    <?= $this->Form->create($ticket) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Ticket') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->control('client');
            echo $this->Form->control('reference');
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Product_Tickets (Ticket items)') ?></legend>
       <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><?= __('Product') ?></th>
                    <th><?= __('Qty') ?></th>
                    <th><?= __('Serial Number') ?></th>
                    <th><?= __('Notes') ?></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>
                <?php echo $this->Form->control("product_tickets.0.product_id", []) ?>
                </td>   
                <td>
                <?php echo $this->Form->control("product_tickets.0.qty", []) ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                <?php echo $this->Form->control("product_tickets.0.serial_number", []) ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                <?php echo $this->Form->control("product_tickets.0.notes", []) ?>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                <?php echo $this->Form->control("product_tickets.1.product_id", []) ?>
                </td>   
                <td>
                <?php echo $this->Form->control("product_tickets.1.qty", []) ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                <?php echo $this->Form->control("product_tickets.1.serial_number", []) ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                <?php echo $this->Form->control("product_tickets.1.notes", []) ?>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                <?php echo $this->Form->control("product_tickets.2.product_id", []) ?>
                </td>   
                <td>
                <?php echo $this->Form->control("product_tickets.2.qty", []) ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                <?php echo $this->Form->control("product_tickets.2.serial_number", []) ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                <?php echo $this->Form->control("product_tickets.2.notes", []) ?>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                <?php echo $this->Form->control("product_tickets.3.product_id", []) ?>
                </td>   
                <td>
                <?php echo $this->Form->control("product_tickets.3.qty", []) ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                <?php echo $this->Form->control("product_tickets.3.serial_number", []) ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                <?php echo $this->Form->control("product_tickets.3.notes", []) ?>
                </td>
                </tr>


            </tbody>
            <tfoot>

            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

*(*Note, there other/better ways to make forms with multiple associated records.)*

In the Tickets controller, in the add method:

```
    public function add()
    {
        $ticket = $this->Tickets->newEntity();     
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $data = $this->request->getData();
            $ticket = $this->Tickets->newEntity($data, [
                'associated' => ['ProductTickets']
            ]); 
            $ticket = $this->Tickets->patchEntity($ticket, $this->request->getData(),['associated' => 'ProductTickets'
              ]);
            if ($this->Tickets->save($ticket)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The ticket has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The ticket could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $products = $this->Tickets->ProductTickets->Products->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('ticket', 'products'));
    }
```

This works for me and should save any combination of product_ids associated to the ticket_id.  For example this request data saves as expected:

```
debug($this->request->getData());
[
    'client' => '1',
    'reference' => 'reference 1',
    'product_tickets' => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'product_id' => '1',
            'qty' => '12',
            'serial_number' => 'abc1234',
            'notes' => 'note1'
        ],
        (int) 1 => [
            'product_id' => '2',
            'qty' => '5',
            'serial_number' => '4321cba',
            'notes' => 'note2'
        ],
        (int) 2 => [
            'product_id' => '1',
            'qty' => '6',
            'serial_number' => 'a4b3c21',
            'notes' => 'note3'
        ],
        (int) 3 => [
            'product_id' => '3',
            'qty' => '21',
            'serial_number' => '4c3b2a1',
            'notes' => 'note4'
        ]
    ]
]
```

Per the manual, [Saving Has Many Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-hasmany-associations)

Important note, if any of the 4 products you plan to save on the ticket is NULL, then you'll need to remove that product from the request data.  You can do this with a [beforeMarshal](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#modifying-request-data-before-building-entities) method in the ProductTicketsTable model.

Hope this is what you had in mind and is helpful.

Cheers,

D.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The difference between your solution and my problem is due to an "S" letter. Notice that the name of my table is "products_tickets" and not "product_tickets" as in your solution. That's why my logic uses "Belongs to many" and in your case is "Has Many". Obviously your solution works and mine does not, so I'm going to implement yours. Unfortunately I'm left with the question of why the other way does not work. Once again, thanks for your response. Greetings.